# Adding Facebook button "report an abuse"

Tags: android, facebook

I would like to integrate the facebook button for "report an abuse" in an android application.
I was able to find how to add the "I like" on the facebook documentation but it was impossible to fin any informations about a "report" button.

Does someone know if it is possible to add a "report an abuse" button? and how to do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to report content on Facebook as breaking the rules - such 'report content' links are rendered by Facebook's own interface. If you want users to be able to report content created in your app, you could add your own reports functionality, but there's no way to hook into Facebook's report mechanisms